# Evaluating: $\lim_{n \to 0} \prod_{\substack{i=nk \\k \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}}}^{2-n} \left( 2-i \right) $

Tags: limits, arithmetic, infinite-product

How would we evaluate:
$$\lim_{n \to 0} \prod_{\substack{i=nk \\k \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}}}^{2-n} \left( 2-i \right) $$

Is it possible to evaluate this manually? Or do we have to make a program to get an approximation?

EDIT:

Since people are getting confused in the comments, here is an example:

If we take n=0.5:

$$\prod_{\substack{i=nk \\k \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}}}^{2-n} \left( 2-i \right) = \prod_{\substack{i=0.5k \\k \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}}}^{1.5} \left( 2-i \right)=(2-0)(2-0.5)(2-1)(2-1.5) $$

Hopes this clears up the misunderstanding.

Comment: What is the value of $$\prod_{i=nk, k \in \{0,1,2..\}}^{2-n} \left( 2-i \right) $$ when $n$ is equal, for example, to $\frac12$?

Comment: What does the product mean when $n$ is irrational?

Comment: @saulspatz I don't exactly understand what you mean by that. We are taking n to be a very small number.

Comment: I just don't understand the notation.  The upper limit isn't an integer.  Several people (including me) have voted to close the question as unclear.  Please give an example of what you mean.

Comment: okay give me a moment to explain what I mean

Comment: @saulspatz now do you get what I mean?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't  Why isn't there a factor of $(2-.5)?$

Comment: @saulspatz sorry really my bad, fixed it now. Havent been getting enough sleep these days. I hope now everything is clear?

Comment: I understand now.  I think it would be clearer to write $$\prod_{0\leq k<2/n}(2-nk)$$

Comment: yes but now with the example I think it would be clear enough for other people to understand.

Comment: @5xum and saulspatz any idea on how to do this question?

Answer (score 2):

The product can be written in an equivalent form as:

$$\Pi(n)=\prod_{k=0}^{\frac{2-n}{n}} (2-kn)=\prod_{k=0}^{\frac{2-n}{n}} -n(k-\frac{2}{n})=\prod_{k=0}^{\frac{2-n}{n}} -n\prod_{k=0}^{\frac{2-n}{n}} (k-\frac{2}{n})=$$
$$=2(-n)^{\frac{2-n}{n}} \left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)_{\frac{2-n}{n}}$$

This may be helpful.

Comment: why is (2-n)/n at the end in subscript?

Comment: It's Pochhammer notation

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this for the limit n tends to 0?

Comment: Do you know how to express this using the gamma function?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a start, but I think you'll be able to carry it to a conclusion.

Let $$f(x)=\prod_{0\leq k<2/x}(2-nk)$$ and consider the sequence $$f\left(\frac12\right),f\left(\frac14\right),\dots,f\left(2^{-n}\right),\dots\tag{1}$$  We have $${f\left(2^{-n-1}\right)\over f\left(2^{-n}\right)}={1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2^{n+2}-1)\over(2^{n+1})^{2^{n+1}}}\tag{2}$$
This is because every other term in the product for $f(2^{-n-1})$ also occurs in the product for $f(2^{-n}),$ and the expression on the right-hand side of $(2)$ is what is left after cancellation.  The expression on the right-hand side of $(2)$ goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty,$ so the sequence in $(1)$ also goes to $0.$

I don't have time right now to try to extend this general $x.$  I would first try to show that if $2^{-n-1}<x<2^{-n}$ then $f\left(2^{-n-1}\right)<f(x)<f\left(2^{-n}\right).$  Of course, if you can show that, you are done.

Comment: I didn't get why the lower limit is $k \lt 2/x $

Comment: From your example, I take it that $xk<2,$ so $k<2/x.$